# How do you add a custom modal segue in xcode?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a application and segues are working fine, but I want to have a segue without any animation (I currently have to choose from Modal, Push, etc, then Cross Dissolve, Flip, etc.). I know I have to use Custom instead of modal then create a class. But I do not know what the correct method is for this.

I think you have to overwrite -(void) perform{} 
but I am not getting it.

If someone could provide me some sample code, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a class that extends UIStoryboardSegue and within that class you create your perform method.

```
- (void)perform
{
    [self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Then in your storyboard, click on the segue connector, set "style" to "custom" and enter the name of your extended class in the "segue class" box.